# PID Integrator component

Tags: pid-controller

I'm trying to understand PIDs and there is just one thing in the general equation that I can't figure out, that is what does the Tau in the integration mean? in the pdf equation 10.1 there is
ki * integral[ e(tau) dtau ] but it doesn't say that it means by tau

http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/AM08/pdf/am06-pid_16Sep06.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tau is just time.  You're integrating that shaded area of the curve from tau = 0 to tau = t.  You might see this written integral[e(t) dt].  But you can't write t here, because t is already in use in the equation.  So tau is just a substitute for t.  Doesn't matter what variable names you use.  You're integrating over time.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense